Latex error: "You can't use `\char"FB' after \advance. \end{widetext}"
Update:
Here is the shared link of this project at Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/3237365147wxtycqjwsmgz#022abd
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am writing a manuscript for a IEEE conference, and my manuscript has this error that I cannot solve (I spent hours on trying to solve it, but cannot). Following is the example Latex code:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{widetext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
    
    \title{Conference Paper Title}
        
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Section I}
    \label{SecAlgorithmDesignMinC}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{widetext}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
                \begin{split}
                    \textrm{B}:&    \quad \rho c_p \frac{dT}{dt} =  -\kappa\Delta T \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \Omega \\
                    \textrm{S}:&    \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt} =   - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \quad && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega \\
                    \textrm{TS}:&   \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt}  =  \frac{(1-\mathcal{R})Pe^{-\tau}}{\pi w^2} e^{-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{w^2}}  - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \\ & - \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T}}\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{M}p(T)  \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega_t
                \end{split}
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{widetext}
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{\strut Title}
        \textbf{INPUT:} 
        \textbf{OUTPUT:} 
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \STATE{Do something}
            \STATE{Do something}                
            \STATE{Do something}                
            \STATE{Do something}                
            \STATE{Do something}                
            \STATE{Do something}                
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    
    \section{Section II}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{widetext}
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
                \begin{split}
                    \textrm{B}:&    \quad \rho c_p \frac{dT}{dt} =  -\kappa\Delta T \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \Omega \\
                    \textrm{S}:&    \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt} =   - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \quad && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega \\
                    \textrm{TS}:&   \quad \frac{1}{A_s}\frac{dT}{dt}  =  \frac{(1-\mathcal{R})Pe^{-\tau}}{\pi w^2} e^{-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{w^2}}  - \epsilon \sigma (T^4 - T_{amb}^4) \\ & - \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T}}\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{M}p(T)  \quad  && \forall \textbf{x} \in \partial \Omega_t
                \end{split}
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{widetext}
        
\end{document}

The error messages I have are:
Test.tex: error: 76: You can't use `\char"FB' after \advance. \end{widetext}
Test.tex: error: 76: Missing number, treated as zero. \end{widetext}
Test.tex: error: 76: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{widetext}
Test.tex: error: 76: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{widetext}

Any help is greatly appreciated.
widetext.sty
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Liam0205/014661fe1fb0c337bfa0dd3242430015/raw/c3f00af1f0a528e84bccf455b7de934e139960b5/widetext.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{widetext}

%% Mimics the widetext environment of revtex4 for any other class package
%% Eg: article.cls
%%
%% Authored by: Liam Huang
%%
%% Advantages:
%% *) Supports float (eg: figure) in two column format (Advantage over
%%      multicol package)
%% *) One and twocolumn exist on the same page
%% *) Flow of text shown via rule
%% *) Equal height of text when in two column format
%%
%% Acknowledgment(s):
%% 1. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, two packages (flushend, cuted) of
%% the sttools bundle are used. The sttools bundle is available from CTAN.
%% Lisence of these packages rests with their corresponding author.
%% Any bug/problem with flushend and cuted should be forwarded to their
%% corresponding package authors.
%% 2. The idea of the rule came from the following latex community website
%% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2770
%%
%% This package just defines the widetext environment and the rules.
%%
%% Usage:
%% \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
%% \usepackage{widetext}
%%
%% \begin{document}
%%
%% Some text in twocolumn
%%
%% \begin{widetext}
%% Text in onecolumn format.
%% \end{widetext}
%%
%% Some more text in twocolumn
%%
%% \end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlength\wttlinewidth
\setlength{\wttlinewidth}{0.4pt}

\@ifpackageloaded{etoolbox}{\relax}{
  \IfFileExists{etoolbox.sty}
      {\RequirePackage{etoolbox}}
      {\typeout{}
      \typeout{Package widetext error: Install the etoolbox package. Available from CTAN.}
      \typeout{}
      \stop
      }
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{widetext}{%
  \renewenvironment{figure}[1][htb]%
  {%
    \let\oldcaption\caption
    \renewcommand\caption{\def\@captype{figure}\oldcaption}%
  }{}
  \renewenvironment{table}[1][htb]%
  {%
    \let\oldcaption\caption
    \renewcommand\caption{\def\@captype{table}\oldcaption}%
  }{}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % Firstly, test which method of two-column document is being used
  \@ifpackageloaded{multicol} % test \ver@multicol.sty
  {
    \newlength\@parindent
    \setlength\@parindent{\parindent}
    \newenvironment{widetext}[1][2]{%
      \gdef\savedcolnum{#1}
      \noindent
      \rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-0.4pt)}{\wttlinewidth}%
      \par %\vspace{6pt}
      \parindent \@parindent
    }{%
        \par
        \hfill
        \rule[0.5\baselineskip]
            {\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-1pt)}{\wttlinewidth}%
    }
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{widetext}{\end{multicols}}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{widetext}{\begin{multicols}{\savedcolnum}}
  }{% if the multicol package is not used, test if LaTeX standard twocolumn is used
    \if@twocolumn
      \@ifpackageloaded{flushend}{\relax}{
        \IfFileExists{flushend.sty}
            {\RequirePackage{flushend}}
            {\typeout{}
            \typeout{Package widetext error: Install the flushend package. Available from CTAN.}
            \typeout{}
            \stop
            }
      }
      \@ifpackageloaded{cuted}{\relax}{
        \IfFileExists{cuted.sty}
            {\RequirePackage{cuted}}
            {\typeout{}
            \typeout{Package widetext error: Install the cuted package. Available from CTAN.}
            \typeout{}
            \stop
            }
      }
      \newlength\@parindent
      \setlength\@parindent{\parindent}
      \newenvironment{widetext}[1][2]
        {%
          \begin{strip}
          \rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-0.4pt)}{\wttlinewidth}%
          \par %\vspace{6pt}
          \parindent \@parindent
        }%
        {%
          \par
          \hfill
          \rule[0.5\baselineskip]
            {\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-1pt)}{\wttlinewidth}
          \end{strip}
        }
    \else
      \newenvironment{widetext}[1][2]{}{}
    \fi
  }
}

\endinput


Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Thanks for providing code and an error message. widetext isn't a standard package, so could you please share where you obtained it? When I grabbed a copy from the Internet, I couldn't reproduce the error messages with your code.

I'm guessing the widetext package itself isn't related to your error, but since I can't reproduce it, I'd suggest commenting out your code piece by piece, until the error disappears. That way, you'll know the bare minimum code needed to reproduce your error, which can help you to troubleshoot more precisely.

Welcome! Please provide a minimal example in your question. Questions shouldn't depend on external links, which change rendering the content here useless to later readers. In order to ensure questions and answers remain meaningful, posts should be self-contained.

@gz839918 Thank you for your quick response. This block of code is kind of weird and sometimes even if there are not errors after rearranging the structure of the code, the generated pdf file misses some components. I have no idea where the missing parts go. Anyway, I just added the overleaf shared link. I would greatly appreciated it if you can offer your insights and guidance.

I'm afraid that's really not how this site works. It's not a reasonable question to ask somebody to review your off-site code. You can hire people to do that. Just this isn't the site for it. Please comment out your code until you have the smallest example which reproduces the error you want help with and post that here.

Check the syntax of the widetext environment, it perhaps takes an argument.

in a full texlive installation your example produces the error ! LaTeX Error: File \widetext.sty' not found please remove all the other unrelated packages in your example but add a copy ofwidetext.styso people can reproduce the error. Presumably you have an error in the use ofwidetext` but as you have not shown how it is defined it is not possible to say what is wrong.

If you use Strip directly, it will work (but you should not use split here). Or you can use widetext once, but you lose any subsequent Strip or widetext content. I don't know what defines \bx@B ...?
